# Jsonschema to validate at least one element in one of the lists is present

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a json, like this:

```
{
  "listA": [
    {
      "prop1": "mine"
    },
     {
      "prop1": "mine"
    }
  ],
  "listB": [
    {
      "prop1": "mine"
    }
  ],
  "propsForAll": {
    "property1": "value",
    "property2": "value"
  }
}
```

I need json schema to validate that at least one element in any of the lists is present {listA, listB, listC}

Currently, my schema looks like this:

```
 "properties": {
 .....
    "listA": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/elementA"
      },
      "minItems": 1
    },
    "listB": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/elementB"
      },
      "minItems": 1
    },
    "listC": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/elementC"
      },
      "minItems": 1
    },
.....
  },
.....
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "required": [
        "listA"
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "listB"
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "listC"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

but if I have listA with one element and listC - empty, I get validation exception, which is not what I need. **I need to have one element in any of the lists, any ideas?**

Comment: You have mentioned minItems as 1. Try removing that.

Comment: yes, but then a json with a single empty list is resolved as valid, which is not true.

Comment: This is actually contradictory. Any 1 means they can be empty. Try using variables then. https://opis.io/json-schema/1.x/variables.html check this.

Comment: I have a solution, but also check your schema because it has `ListA` rather than `listA`.

Comment: @VisakhVijayan "variables" isn't part of the JSON Schema specification. That specific implementation lists some extra features they have added, that being one.

Comment: @Relequestual the capital letter is typo when composing the question.

Comment: Great! It's usually better if you can provide the REAL schema chunks to provide additional context, but in this situation it was OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `minItems: 1` constraint to your `anyOf` subschemas.

Here's a live demo: https://jsonschema.dev/s/RszNl

```
{
  "properties": {
    "listA": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
 
      }
    },
    "listB": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {

      }
    },
    "listC": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {

      }
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "required": [
        "listA"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "listA": {
          "minItems": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "listB"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "listB": {
          "minItems": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "listC"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "listC": {
          "minItems": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: let me try this out, might be what I am looking for!!

Comment: Do you understand how this is different? If not, I'm happy to explain.

Comment: yes! perfectly understood, I am quite new to json schema - simply I do not know what is possible and what - not, yet.
and it works like charm! thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! We monitor StackOverflow for the jsonschema tag, and we also have a friendly slack server. Check https://json-schema.org.